# Import Voice Memos back to iOS

Tags: ios, import, voice-memo

For some time ago, I've exported my voice memos from my iPhone to my Mac for back-up purposes using iExplorer and deleted the originals.

Now, again using iExplorer, I tried to copy them back to my iPhone, to their original place although nothing copied showed up under Voice Memos. Probably iOS has a database file concerning the recordings. I've the previous database as well but copying it will for sure mess up the current new recordings under iOS.

The web is crowded with how to export your voice memos to your Mac but no one is talking about how to import them back to your iPhone and since my try failed, is anyone aware of a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to sync the voice memos via iTunes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have Apple Music so iTunes (on Windows) doesn't work the way it works when you're syncing your MP3s. I tried to import my voice memos into iTunes but it just wouldn't sync them. Things I tried:

- dragging the audio file into the "Voice Memos" playlist and syncing but it didn't work.
- discovering the location of the Voice Memos on my filesystem (`C:\iTunes\iTunes\iTunes Media\Voice Memos`), copying them there, and trying to sync

What finally worked but that wasn't ideal was:

1. sending them from my computer via email
2. selecting the file and then exporting it to Voice Memos

Drawback was I lost the original file date. I probably could adjust the file date by writing a little app to do that, but this works for now.
*